# aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, buildbox

Hello friend how are you i am beginner in android try make game on buildbox after import game in on android  studio change the package name i recieved this error please help how to solve this issue without change package name its work fine here error what aidl.exe error here i dont know if any expert help  please tell me

```
Process 'command 'C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Cause 1: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71bb5f2955f4df269bed9144a4b03bf9\support-compat-25.2.0\aidl -dC:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1312833214387911164.d E:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.await(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:102)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter.close(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:118)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile.doTaskAction(AidlCompile.java:161)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:51)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(AndroidVariantTask.kt:31)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:91)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71bb5f2955f4df269bed9144a4b03bf9\support-compat-25.2.0\aidl -dC:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1312833214387911164.d E:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:593)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1005)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71bb5f2955f4df269bed9144a4b03bf9\support-compat-25.2.0\aidl -dC:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1312833214387911164.d E:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable.run(AidlCompile.java:293)
    at com.android.ide.common.workers.ExecutorServiceAdapter$submit$submission$1.run(ExecutorServiceAdapter.kt:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedRunnableAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71bb5f2955f4df269bed9144a4b03bf9\support-compat-25.2.0\aidl -dC:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1312833214387911164.d E:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.AidlProcessor.call(AidlProcessor.java:147)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(DirectoryWalker.java:313)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DirectoryWalker$1.visitFile(DirectoryWalker.java:308)
    at java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Files.java:2670)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.DirectoryWalker.walk(DirectoryWalker.java:304)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AidlCompile$AidlCompileRunnable.run(AidlCompile.java:291)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing process C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe with arguments {-pC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-28\framework.aidl -oE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\build\generated\aidl_source_output_dir\debug\compileDebugAidl\out -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\debug\aidl -IE:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl -IC:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\71bb5f2955f4df269bed9144a4b03bf9\support-compat-25.2.0\aidl -dC:\Users\JOSHUA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl1312833214387911164.d E:\codecanyon-21933926-monster-truck-machine-gun-with-admob-banner-interstitial-android-studio-project\Monster truck Machine Gun (Android Studio)\android\app\src\main\aidl\com\android\vending\billing\IInAppBillingService.aidl}
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.buildProcessException(GradleProcessResult.java:73)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:48)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.AidlProcessor.call(AidlProcessor.java:145)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\JOSHUA-PC\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aidl.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
    at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:396)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:46)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AIDL then package names matters.
The aidl file of your client and service should be on the same package or else you will get the error: "finished with non-zero exit value 1"